Function Hangs Indefinitely (Selenium Web Driver, C#)
I am making a script that scrapes some data off a website. But My web is hanging indefinitely and VS doesnt throw any error or end the test at all. It just hangs forever. I dont see which part of the code its causing the hang, I am so confused.
Here is the code:
public void scrapping() {

WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
for (int i = 0; i < currentPage; i++)
{
    try
    {
        IWebElement chkbox = wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("checkboxCol")));
        chkbox.Click();
        IWebElement next = wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"searchResults\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]")));
        next.Click();
        wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(next));
        wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(chkbox));


    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Captcha Detected");
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            //Captcha(); // Empty function 
        }
    }
}

I tried playing around with the timing for the wait1, instead of Element Visible, I tried different ones. Not getting anywhere.

"I dont see which part of the code its causing the hang" - When you step through the code using a debugger, what specifically happens?

Adding what @David said you could also pause the project if it's running on debug mode and see where it is hanging. Or recording a profile of your running project to see what causes it.

As others have mentioned in comments, it sounds like you need a good, honest debugging session in Visual Studio. Step through the code line by line until you find the problem. That being said, I'm going to guess it is the infinite loop in your catch:
while (true)
{
    // true is always true, even if you sleep, so this never exits.
}

I bet the code is throwing an exception, and then it falls into an infinite loop.
